# tell apache virtual hosts to connect to php-fpm sockets using different user/group each

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm

I've been reading the php-fpm [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php#listen-owner) and found out that I can give each socket its own user, group and mode, but how can I tell apache (per vhost I mean) to use x user and y group to connect to the sockets?

What I want to achieve is to prevent pools from reading each other files, in case of breach, only the files for that domain would be leaked and nothing else. I know how I can do this for the fpm pools using the `user` and `group` settings and then giving the file structure their proper permissions. But what about the same http user being able to access all fpm sockets? Should I be concerned about that or not?

pool1.conf (php-fpm)

```
[pool1]
user = domain1
group = domain1
listen = /run/php-fpm/www.domain1.sock
listen.owner = http
listen.group = http
listen.mode = 0660
```

domain1.conf (apache virtual host)

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain1.com
    ServerName www.domain1.com

    DocumentRoot "/srv/http/domain1.com/www"
    <Directory "/srv/http/domain1.com/www">
        <IfModule dir_module>
            DirectoryIndex index.php
        </IfModule>

        <Files "index.php">
            SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm/www.domain1.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
        </Files>

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
            RewriteRule . index.php [L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem"
    Protocols h2 h2c
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;"
    ErrorLog "/srv/protected/sites/domain1.com/logs/www-error_log"
    CustomLog "/srv/protected/sites/domain1.com/logs/www-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm also trying to figure out why does the default value for `listen.mode` is `0660`? Why does the http group need read+write permissions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but here's how I understand it to work. Each process runs as a system (service) user. Apache is a process and runs as its user (`http` in your example). I think that in order to achieve what you want you would need to spawn a separate apache process with its own user.

To do this, though, you'd also need to put each user/site on its own port and then have a reverse proxy on the same machine that listens on port 80/443 and accesses the corresponding sites accordingly.

This is actually not a bad setup as it also gives you the opportunity to add mod_security on the proxy server and cover all sites at once.

So, in short, PHP-FPM is not the solution you are looking for (if I've understood your question correctly). The `listen.user` directive must be the same as the user that apache is running as.

Comment: Yes, I know, I have as many sockets as pools but that's not the problem. What I'm asking here is how can I make httpd user different users/groups to read the sockets. httpd uses the http user/group, but i want different users, preferably the same user/group the php-fpm pools are using.

Comment: I added clarification about how to change the user. Please let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: Yes it is clear, but again, that's what I already had working (did you read my original post? right below pool1.conf I'm already doing that). I don't want php-fpm to create all sockets with the same user/group and I can only tell php-fpm to use different user/group if I can make the apache virtualhosts use different user/group to read the sockets. So the problem here is apache, does apache supports doing this? maybe through modules? That would be a proper answer.

Comment: Sorry. Updated answer. I honestly hadn't understood what you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

maybe apache2-mpm-itk would do it
https://cloudkul.com/blog/apache-virtual-hosting-with-different-users/

Comment: Whoa, mpm-itk is still alive? Official site says not updated since 2016. I doubt it is good idea to use a web server module which requires running as root and which wasn't updated for 5 years.

Comment: Wouldn't recommend mpm-itk, doesn't fork processes like other mpm modules (despite the name)